# Access Google Spreadsheet revision history through API

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there any way I could access Google Spreadsheet revision history through the API?

The reason for that is I have a lot of sheets and simply relying on build-in revision history does not suffice to point me to the sheet where changes were made. I need to check *all* the sheets to figure out what change was made - highly inefficient approach.

The output I would expect is:

```
Changes made at 01 Jan 2010 by SomeUser 
Sheet name: Sheet1
Updates:
[{
address: C1,
oldValue: OldValue,
newValue: NewValue
},
{
address: B2,
oldValue: OldValue,
newValue: NewValue
}, 
...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using logging from Google App Script to file.

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var observableSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];
  var ignoredUsers = ["ignored_user@gmail.com", "ignored_user2@gmail.com"];
  var current = new Date();

  Logger.log("%s - %s", "Change Logger", new Date());

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var val = r.getValue();
  var activeCellAddress = r.getA1Notation();
  var sheetName = s.getName();

  if (observableSheets.indexOf(sheetName) > -1 && r.getRow() > 1) {
    Logger.log("Change in %s sheet detected", sheetName);
    Logger.log("Cell change at: %s", activeCellAddress);
    Logger.log("value of active cell: %s", val);
  }

  var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (ignoredUsers.indexOf(sessionEmail) > -1) {
    return;
  }
  SaveLogToFile();
}
```

Comment: The question asks for 'access Google Spreadsheet revision history through the API.' The code in the answer does not attempt to retrieve the revision history but logs events starting at the point in time when `onEdit(e)` is first bound to the spreadsheet, which is a different thing. See [Logging a value that changes once a day in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153193).

Answer (score -2):

This is now pretty straight forward with the event object.  [I wrote this article with script example](http://blog.prolecto.com/2016/10/30/how-to-google-sheet-script-to-edit-cell-contents/) to show how it is done.

http://blog.prolecto.com/2016/10/30/how-to-google-sheet-script-to-edit-cell-contents/

Comment: We like answers to be self-contained. Links are great for supplemental information, but if a reader has to follow the link in order to get to any useful information it's not considered a good answer. Further, when a new user shows up and posts a content-light answer with a link elsewhere it looks spammy.

Comment: The linked article doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Ruben It's true that this doesn't answer the question (which  BTW, is a VERY interesting technical issue), but then neither does the OP's own answer address their question per se.

Comment: @Tedinoz I agree with you :)